# Can we use "Result" instead of "Conclusion" as a title in a paper/article?

Tags: word-choice, writing, academia

My paper is about computer science and I want to use one of these words as the title of a section. Which word should I use: *result* or *conclusion*?

Comment: Typically, in academic papers, conclusions are presented based on results, so either or both may be significant in your case. You should probably give more details.

Comment: You appear to have asked two questions on basically the same thing; this question and [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/342727/184766)

Comment: A result is basically what you get from some experiment or research project.  A conclusion is what you claim to have learned from the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both. You would typically have the results and **then** the conclusion. The object of a conclusion is to synthesize the results or raw data.

For instance, when I've written scientific lab reports for classes like AP Biology, the categories were **Abstract**, **Title**, **Introduction**, **Materials and Methods**, **Results and Discussion**, **Conclusion**, and **Literature Cited**, with tables and figures interspersed with full pages dedicated.